# Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int : UIColor]' with an index of type 'NSNumber'

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

Good day. I was trying to follow this tutorial [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jJiqzbzutU`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jJiqzbzutU) and had this error message  Cannot subscript a value of type '[Int : UIColor]' with an index of type `NSNumber`. I did the same thing he did in the tutorial and this went wrong. Please help. The error comes from this line of code

`self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.major]`.

Here is my code for reference.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
let region1 = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "myuuidString")!, identifier: "skybeacon1")

let colors = [2: UIColor.redColor(), 1: UIColor.blueColor()]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    locationManager.delegate = self

    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() != CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{ $0 .proximity != CLProximity.Unknown }
    if knownBeacons.count > 0 {
        let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] as CLBeacon
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.major]
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `closestBeacon.major` is a `NSNumber`. And you want a `int` for self.colors[myInt]. So you need to convert `closestBeacon.major` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello  If you're programming in swift 4, use:

```
closestBeacon.major.intValue
```

instead of

```
closestBeacon.major.integerValue
```

Answer (score 0):

`CLBeacon.major` is a property that returns a `NSNumber`. Just use `closestBeacon.major.integerValue`

Comment: This one fixed it same for closestBeacon.major as Int. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumber` and `Int` are different but related, just cast it (not forced)

```
let closestBeacon = knownBeacons[0] // as CLBeacon is not needed, the compiler knows the type
self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[closestBeacon.major as Int]
```